# Using pseudo code to style radio button with styled-components

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm starting to understand how styled-components work, but one of the features I'm having issues with is pseudo code.  For me, at the moment, doesn't seem to work as expected.  I want the radio button to display a check within the button.  The button is being styled properly, but the check mark is not appearing.

Styled Component

```
export const FormRadio = styled.input.attrs(props => ({
    type: 'radio',
    name: 'action',
    id: 'action-radio-1',
    value: props.value,
}))`
    appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #254294;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 0.274vw;
    outline: none;

    &:checked::before {
        position: absolute;
        font: 17px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        left: 0.45em;
        top: 0.12em;
        content: '\02143';
        transform: rotate(40deg);
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your content seems to be breaking it. and since it's positioned `absolute`, you need to add `width` and `height` to the styling.

so, something like this should work (please note, i simplified the component to focus on the `checked:before` :

```
const Test = styled.input`
&[type="radio"]{

  position: absolute
  &:checked:before{
      content:"";
      font: 17px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background:orange;
      border-radius: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

}

`;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually finally figured it out by doing some triage and noticed when I removed the content property, it started showing.  Odd that content value doesn't work since it works in standard CSS, but either way, it's good now.

Comment: yeah i think it has more to do with the input and not necessarily with standard css vs styled-components, but i found this really odd too!